# How do i input an array from the keyboard in TCL?

Tags: tcl

```
while { $index < $num } {
   set arr(index) [gets stdin]
   incr index 
}
```

This is my code. While trying to output a particular array value , I get the error saying :

```
can't read "arr(2)": no such element in array
    while executing
"puts $arr($index)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `arr($index)` instead of `arr(index)`, as in

```
set arr($index) [gets stdin]
```

Otherwise, all your inputs will end up in the array member `arr(index)` instead of `arr(0)`, `arr(1)`, etc.